# unable to read xml child nodes using vbscript

Tags: xml, vbscript

I want to validate xml childnodes like I want to check if node `<PNAME>` value is staring with `<I>` then `<PTYP>` and `<PGROUP>` values should be start with letter "I" only otherwise script should display error.
This is my xml file.

```
<PARAMETER>
<ETPAR_GUIX>
 <item>
 <PNAME>COAS_1</PNAME>
 <PTYP>X</PTYP>
 <PDESC>Generated Table for View</PDESC>
 <PINDEX>0001</PINDEX>
 <PGROUP>GETTAB</PGROUP>
 <XMLREF_TYP>T</XMLREF_TYP>
 <PSTRUC_TYP>T</PSTRUC_TYP>
 <PREF_TYPE>VIEW</PREF_TYPE>
 <PREF_NAME>COAS</PREF_NAME>
 <PDATLEN>0000</PDATLEN>
 <PINTLEN>000000</PINTLEN>
 <PDECIMALS>000000</PDECIMALS>
 <SORT_LNR>0001</SORT_LNR>
 <PREF_NAME2>COAS</PREF_NAME2>
 <VAL_TYPE>T</VAL_TYPE>
 <TAB_INDEX>0</TAB_INDEX>
 <DEEP_STRU>
     <xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"                       targetNamespace="http://xml.sap.com/2003/05/eCATT/ddic" version="1.0">
 <xsd:complexType name="COAS">
 <annotation>
                        <documentation>I==O==C=S=K==D=COAS=A==L=000000=doc=Generated Table for View</documentation>
</annotation>
<sequence>
<element name="MANDT" minOccurs="0">
<annotation>
                                    <documentation>I==O==C==K=X=D=MANDT=A=C=L=000003=doc=Client</documentation>
</annotation>
    <simpleType>
<restriction base="string">
                                           <maxLength value="3"/>
                                      </restriction>
</simpleType>
</element>
<element name="AUFNR" minOccurs="0">
<annotation>
                                    <documentation>I==O==C==K=X=D=AUFNR=A=C=L=000012=doc=Order Number</documentation>
</annotation>
<simpleType>
<restriction base="string">
<maxLength value="12"/>
</restriction>
</simpleType>
</element>
 </DEEP_STRU>                       
 </item>
 <item>
    <PNAME>I_ORDER_NUMBER_FROM_TABLE</PNAME>
    <PTYP>I</PTYP>
    <PDESC>Generated Table for View</PDESC>
    <PINDEX>0001</PINDEX>
    <PGROUP>I.01</PGROUP>
    <XMLREF_TYP>T</XMLREF_TYP>
    <PSTRUC_TYP>T</PSTRUC_TYP>
    <PREF_TYPE>VIEW</PREF_TYPE>
    <PREF_NAME>COAS</PREF_NAME>
    <PDATLEN>0000</PDATLEN>
    <PINTLEN>000000</PINTLEN>
    <PDECIMALS>000000</PDECIMALS>
    <SORT_LNR>0001</SORT_LNR>
    <PREF_NAME2>COAS</PREF_NAME2>
    <VAL_TYPE>T</VAL_TYPE>
    <TAB_INDEX>0</TAB_INDEX>
    <DEEP_STRU>
     <xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"                       targetNamespace="http://xml.sap.com/2003/05/eCATT/ddic" version="1.0">
 <xsd:complexType name="COAS">
 <annotation>
                        <documentation>I==O==C=S=K==D=COAS=A==L=000000=doc=Generated Table for View</documentation>
</annotation>
<sequence>
<element name="MANDT" minOccurs="0">
<annotation>
                                    <documentation>I==O==C==K=X=D=MANDT=A=C=L=000003=doc=Client</documentation>
</annotation>
    <simpleType>
<restriction base="string">
                                           <maxLength value="3"/>
                                      </restriction>
</simpleType>
</element>
<element name="AUFNR" minOccurs="0">
<annotation>
                                    <documentation>I==O==C==K=X=D=AUFNR=A=C=L=000012=doc=Order Number</documentation>
</annotation>
<simpleType>
<restriction base="string">
<maxLength value="12"/>
</restriction>
</simpleType>
</element>
 </DEEP_STRU>
   </item>
</ETPAR_GUIX>
</PARAMETER>
```

Please provide solution in vbscript with same above condition for validation of letter staring with "V" and "E" also. The following vbscript code is working for only such xml which contains 3 or 4 item nodes But My xml contains 50 item nodes. So i could not find the solution for this so please help me

My Vbscript

```vb
XMLDataFile = "D:\Automation\newparamters.xml"
Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
xmlDoc.Async = False
xmlDoc.Load(XMLDataFile)
    xmlDoc.validateOnParse = True  
    If xmlDoc.Load(XMLDataFile) Then 
         MsgBox "SUCCESS loading XML File"  
    Else  
         MsgBox "ERROR loading XML File"  
    End If
    counter=0  
    Set root = xmlDoc.documentElement
    Set items = root.childNodes
    for each item in items
       myPNAME = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("PNAME").item(counter).text
       myPTYP = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("PTYP").item(counter).text
       myPGROUP = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("PGROUP").item(counter).text
       If (Left(myPNAME, 1) = "I") Then
              msgbox("myPNAME Starts with I")
              IsValid = True
            If (Left(myPTYP, 1) <> "I") Then
                IsValid = False
            End If
           If (Left(myPGROUP, 1) <> "I" )Then
                    IsValid = False
           End If
           If IsValid = False Then
                msgbox(myPNAME & " is not valid.")
           End If
           IsValid = True
      End If
      counter=counter+1
   next
```

In above code if i write Set items = root.childNodes then in xml file root node should be 1 but I have another root node like `<ETPAR_GUIX>` and in this root node contains all subnodes like `<item>` so please provide solution for how to check or validate child of child node.

Comment: you should provide what you've tried so far in coding the vbscript you want.. unless, it's hard to get SO friends' response..

Comment: @YohanesKhosiawan许先汉 I have provided my vbscript code now please provide solution for this. Thank You in advance...

Comment: Your XML is invalid, so `xmlDoc` doesn't contain any data. You don't detect this, because you assumed that the `Load` method would return success/failure of the load operation. Which it doesn't. You need to evaluate the `ParseError` property after attempting to load an XML file: `If xmlDoc.ParseError <> 0 Then : WScript.Echo xmlDoc.ParseError.Reason : WScript.Quit : End If`

Comment: Hi now i'm able to run this code but facing problem when we have more than 1 root node like if we have xml file `<PARAMETER>`then `<ESCT>`and our whole xml code `</ESCT></PARAMETER>` root.childNodes this command is not working properly any solution for this. If we want to read like root.childnode.childnodes..? please help

Comment: Please do not move the target. If you have a new question: post it as a new question.